# How to modify this code to send a unique data file per pulse?

Tags: python, arduino-ide, arduino-uno

***I still don't understand how to only capture one pulse per data file***

My professor and I are trying to modify the code below to send a uniquely named .txt file after every pulse we receive from our Arduino.So far, our efforts have been fruitless.  Right now it sends us all of the data received after a period of time and compiles all of the pulse data into one file. Since the file name isn't changing that data stored in the file is only temporary.

The Arduino Sketch is called Girino and can be found [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Girino-Fast-Arduino-Oscilloscope/?ALLSTEPS). The code that we wish to modify is the accompanying python code called readgirino.py that's found under Step #23.
I think we have to modify this loop;

```
for i in range(5):
    stream.write('s')
    eventString = stream.read(1280)
    eventData.append(np.array(unpack( '1280B', eventString )))
    print eventData
    stream.write('S')
    stream.flushInput()

np.savetxt( "data.txt", eventData[4] )
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

UPDATE
-Creating a unique file name was solved with:

> ```
>   stream.write('S')
>     stream.flushInput()
>     n = n + 1
> ```

```
np.savetxt( "data" +str( n) + ".txt", eventData[4] )
```

Although I still don't understand how to only capture one pulse per data file.

---

The Girino code makes no mention of eventData, but I think it means the array that appears in my terminal window after I run the readgirino.py code:
Girino tells me that it is ready
Buffer size: 1280

Baud rate: 115200

Wait duration: 1248

Prescaler: 128

Trigger event: 3

Threshold: 127

Setting prescaler to: 128

Setting threshold to: 50

Buffer size: 1280

Baud rate: 115200

Wait duration: 1248

Prescaler: 128

Trigger event: 3

Threshold: 50

[array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0])]
[array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0])]
[array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0])]
[array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0])]
[array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0])]

Answer (score 0):

Change the "data.txt" in

```
np.savetxt( "data.txt", eventData[4] )
```

to something that changes every pulse. You can increment a number (data1.txt, data2.txt) for instance.

```
namestr = "data" + str(n) + ".txt"
n = n + 1
```

If you want to save the constituent arrays in eventData to different files, you'll need an additional for loop:

```
for event in eventData:
    n = n + 1
    np.savetxt( "data" + str(n) + ".txt", event )
```

Comment: Change it to something like: ....   np.savetxt( "data"+str(int(time.time()))+".txt", eventData[4] ) ......?

Comment: You can also use the current time, yes. Anything that changes every pulse.

Comment: Cool it worked, I used:                              stream.write('S')
        stream.flushInput()
        n = n + 1
        
        
 np.savetxt( "data" +str( n) + ".txt", eventData[4] )

Comment: Would you happen to have any suggestions on how to edit the loop above? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I need more information about what is inside eventData to answer that.